# Build flavor with custom sourseset

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, source-sets

My project contains multiple flavor and main folder which contains common logic when i build project with a specific flavor gradle use values from main folder even if that value is present in that flavor

Please help

Project structure

- MainProject

  - src

    - **main**    (main project)

      - java
    - **flavor1**

      - java/Appconstant.java
    - **flavor2**

      - java/Appconstant.java
    - ...

build.gradle file

```
  productFlavors {

        flavor1 {
            applicationId <pkgName>
            versionCode 15
            versionName "2.4.0"    
        }

        flavor2 {
           applicationId  <pkgName>
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"

        }

 }

sourceSets {
        flavor1 {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/res']
        }
         flavor2 {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/res']
        }


    }
```

[image: App structure]

[image]

**EDIT**
modified project structure as per suggestion but now flavor class in not visible in Main

Comment: You do not need `sourceSets` section because you have standard project layout.

Comment: @mixel ok so when to use `sourseSets` can you provide detail..... for me its little condufing

Comment: You should use `sourceSet` section when your source sets have custom location.

Comment: now i'm getting duplicate class error..

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of your full project structure?

Comment: @mixel I have edited question

Comment: `build.gradle` should be in `app` directory.

Comment: You can't use the same class in Main and in a flavor.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I made changes in Main but now classes in flavors are not visible by classes in main. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Prachi build.gradle seems to be in the wrong folder. It should be at the same level of src, and not inside src.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti ya build.gradle is at the same level of src

Comment: Are you using the same package name?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes... if i build project with flavor one it works fine but for flavor two i'm getting error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91693/discussion-between-gabriele-mariotti-and-prachi).